# Try/catch around database connection?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am making a site and i use entity framework to connect to the database.
Should I put a

```
    try
    {
var query = from es in gr.sales
                        orderby es.tilbudsNavn
                        select es;
    }
    catch
{
lblError = "Sorry but you can't connecto to the database right now, try again later";
}
```

around all my database connections??

Comment: there needs to be more information here.  Why do you think you need a try catch around every connection, what errors are you afraid will happen?  Are you using any kind of logger (log4net) that would log those errors etc..  Generally if you have an error, you want to do something with it, at the very least, it should let you know something is wrong so you can fix it.

Comment: It depends on the context. If you want to provide a "Try Again" button if it fails then yes. If you're not going to do anything and redirect them to an error page then don't handle it there and let it bubble up to your next exception handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not - unless you want to ignore cases where you can't connect to your database (which would probably render it useless). Some appropriate error handling where you redirect to an error page and if possible perform some sort of notification (i.e. send you an email with details of what the error was) would be much more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You should manage access to your database from one single place. And, yes, in that single place, the connect-statement should be surrounded with try-catch to facilitate logging and error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea using try catch statements to handle any possible errors. File handling, database handling, any i/o with your app is usually a good idea to wrap in error handling code that hopefully can recover the error or quit with an informative message and notification to user and admin.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you can do something useful in your `catch`clause. By no means use an empty catch clause as that will swallow all your db errors.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create one method with Try-Catch with several params, one of them is lambda or func or action you want to execute.

So all your handling will be in one place.

Also, you may read about here [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/shivprasadk/aspect-oriented-programming-in-C-Sharp-net-part-i/) or [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx

There is a good article about exceptions by Eric Lippert. It describes what should be catched and what not.

As for your example, I'd put a Database Connection Exception to the "exogenous" kind which should be catched. At least for a proper error handling and if the DB Access is critical, shut your app down with the appropriate message / logging.